# How to set loading(resistance) when i try to simulation Darlington pair limit current between Voltage 9 to 36

Tags: simulation, current-limiting, pspice, darlington

How do I set my loading (R13) value for simulating Darlington limit current between 9 to 36 V?

If there is no loading (R13), the result of Q1 current (C to E) would not show correctly, but a placing fixed resistance such as 1k does not simulate how much current the Darlington will be limited in this circuit when changing the voltage range. I think current should increase as voltage is decreased.

[image]

Comment: r=u/i simple as that

Comment: Where did you get this circuit? Where does the load go?

Comment: @Elliot Alderson
1.from my colleague's design. this circuit is used to against Load dump in automotive test item(5b).  i would like to design this circuit can work at 9V~36V. current design does not work at 9V due to darlington limit current from battery . PS: My colleague does not know how to modify this .......     2. the circuit connect with 5V buck IC  so i assume there is resistance loading at input of 5V . is it correct?

Answer (score 0):

R13 is obviously the load. I could not read the tiny part number of the zener diode because the parts are too far apart on your schematic causing the text to be tiny so I cropped and enlarged the schematic.

The datasheet for the zener diode says it is 33V so your circuit **will not work.**

[image: voltage]

Comment: i update my circuit that make more clear

Comment: this circuit can work at 24V~36V  but not work under 13V   and then i update my circuit that make more clear